# I have proved that 1 + 1 = 0

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing

I have proved that 1 + 1 = 0 in one of my questions where a field was given. I was wondering if it is true in every field we have 1 + 1 = 0. Also i was wondering (i know how to prove 1 + 1 = 0) can you prove 0 + 0 = 1 the same way as 1 + 1 = 0?

Comment: Clearly we do not have $1+1 = 0$ in every field (take the reals or the rationals for example). And we never have $0+0 = 1$.

Comment: Perhaps you could give us your proof?

Comment: @MarkBennet That might be Pandora's box ...

Comment: This situation is called ***characteristic 2***

Answer (score 7):

It is certainly not the case that 1+1=0 in *every* field; e.g., the rationals, the reals, the complex numbers, the $p$-adics, the integers modulo 17, . . .

There are fields in which 1+1=0 - this property is called *characteristic 2*. More generally, for any prime $p$, there are fields in which 1+1+ . . . +1 ($p$ times) equals 0; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_(algebra).

On the other hand, if 0+0=1, then we would have 0=1, which is prohibited by the field axioms.

On the other other hand, there are algebraic structures - non-unital rings (rngs) - in which 0=1 is possible; on the other other other hand, that only happens for the trivial rng, so it's not very interesting.

Comment: Surely if there is a four-armed man, there can be a [field with one element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_with_one_element), right? :)